# 'minimum width' no effect on node with horizontal multipart

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have a multi-parts node `N1`, below it a node `N2`,I wish `N1` to have same width as `N2`. 
I have set `minimum width=3cm` for  `every node` but this did not have any impact on `N1` node !?

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.multipart}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2,every node/.style={fill=blue!10,minimum width=3cm,draw}]

\node(N1)[rectangle split, rectangle split parts=3,rectangle split horizontal]
{a\nodepart{two}b\nodepart{three}c};

\node[yshift=-1cm,anchor=north](N2) at (N1.south){d};


\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could misuse the `text width` which does get taken in account for the node parts. However you need to subtract the `inner xsep`s as well as the inner `linewidth`s.

As a non-empty `text width` value activates a `minipage`-like environment for the node part texts you need something like `align=center` if you want to have the texts back in the center.

Note, that the property “minimum” is lost for the node parts/the whole node.

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.multipart}
\tikzset{stretch split horizontal/.style={text width=(\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/minimum width}-
  (\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/rectangle split parts}-1)*\pgflinewidth)
  /(\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/rectangle split parts})-2*(\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/inner xsep})}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2, every node/.style={fill=blue!10, minimum width=3cm, draw}]
\node (N1) [rectangle split, rectangle split parts=5, rectangle split horizontal,
  stretch split horizontal, align=center]
  {a \nodepart{two} b \nodepart{three} c \nodepart{four} d \nodepart{five} e};
\node[yshift=-1cm,anchor=north] (N2) at (N1.south) {d};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

From page 726 in pgfmanual:

> When split vertically, the rectangle split will meet any `minimum width`
>   requirements, but any `minimum height` will be ignored. Conversely when
>   split horizontally, `minimum height` requirements will be met, but any
>   `minimum width` will be ignored. In addition, `inner sep` is applied to
>   every part that is used, so it cannot be speciﬁed independently for a
>   particular part.

Two alternative solutions:

The first one uses a `matrix` of nodes instead of a `multipart` nodes. I know they are not the same, so some tricks are required to convert a `matrix` to something similar to a `multipart` node. In this case I've used a `\vphantom` option but a `minimum height` could also serve. And I also defined `minimum width` for every node in `matrix` as 1/3 from `d` node width.

The second one, draws nodes the other way, first three nodes a, b, c are drawn and second node `d` adjust its size with `fit`. In this case, fitting node content must be written with `label` options.

```
\documentclass[border=5mm,tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,positioning,fit}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2, every node/.style={fill=blue!10,minimum width=3cm,draw}]

\matrix (N1) [matrix of nodes, inner sep=0pt, nodes={fill=blue!10, minimum width=1cm, inner sep=.3333em}, column sep=-\pgflinewidth, draw=none]
{a\vphantom{d} & b & c\vphantom{d}\\};

\node[yshift=-1cm,anchor=north](N2) at (N1.south){d};

\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2, every node/.style={fill=blue!10,minimum width=1cm,draw, minimum height=5mm}]

\begin{scope}[node distance=0pt]
\node(A) {a};\node[right=of A] (B) {b};\node[right=of B] (C) {c};
\end{scope}

\node[fit=(A.north west) (C.south east), inner sep=0pt, below=1cm of B.south, label=center:d] (N2) {};


\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks @Ignasi , but I need solution with `shapes.multipart` library.