# Define function in a let-Block

Tags: tikz-pgf

is there a way to define a function in a let-Block? I have some code that creates a frame and puts two nodes into it:

```latex
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node (frame) [minimum width=4.5cm, minimum height=.5cm, draw=black, rounded corners=.1cm, anchor=east] at (0,0) {};
    \draw[-, dashed] let \p1=(frame.north west), \p2=(frame.south east), \n1={.5*(\x2-\x1)} in (\x1+\n1, \y1) -- (\x1+\n1, \y2);

    \path let \p1=(frame.north west), \p2=(frame.south east), \n1={.25*(\x2-\x1)}, \n2={.5*(\y1-\y2)} in node [align=center] at (\x1+\n1, \y1-\n2) { Left };
    \path let \p1=(frame.north west), \p2=(frame.south east), \n1={.75*(\x2-\x1)}, \n2={.5*(\y1-\y2)} in node [align=center] at (\x1+\n1, \y1-\n2) { Right };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The code to create the two nodes (Left and Right) is pretty similar and I need code like this very often. What I would like to write instead of the two `\path let ..` lines is something like:

```latex
    \path let \p1=(frame.north west), \p2=(frame.south east), \f{v}={v*(\x2-\x1)}, \n2={.5*(\y1-\y2)} in
        node [align=center] at (\x1+\f{.25}, \y1-\n2) { Left }
        node [align=center] at (\x1+\f{.75}, \y1-\n2) { Right };
```

So instead of writing the two separate lines I define a function `f(v)={v*(\x2-\x1)}` which I can call twice to define where those two nodes will be drawn. The complete code would look like:

```latex
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node (frame) [minimum width=4.5cm, minimum height=.5cm, draw=black, rounded corners=.1cm, anchor=east] at (0,0) {};
    \draw[-, dashed] let \p1=(frame.north west), \p2=(frame.south east), \n1={.5*(\x2-\x1)} in (\x1+\n1, \y1) -- (\x1+\n1, \y2);

    \path let \p1=(frame.north west), \p2=(frame.south east), \f{v}={v*(\x2-\x1)}, \n2={.5*(\y1-\y2)} in
        node [align=center] at (\x1+\f{.25}, \y1-\n2) { Left }
        node [align=center] at (\x1+\f{.75}, \y1-\n2) { Right };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Any ideas for how to do this? Thanks in advance for any help!

Greetings,
Sebastian

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx! In your last code block, "The complete code would look like:" you use `\n` both as a `let` variable and as the name of a function definition `\n{d}`. That's a bit confusing, so maybe you should change the function to `\f` or something to make it a bit clearer what is what. Or maybe I just misunderstood your code example?

Comment: @Fritz Yeah you are right there, I changed the code. Sorry for that!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are at least two possible solutions. Note that in both cases, you have to surround your x-coordinate with braces if you want to use parentheses inside the expression. See [Arithmetic in tikz coordinates (parentheses)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/218541/12440) for the reason.

However, one could argue whether defining a function for something this simple is a bit overkill. The tradeoff you should *always* consider is whether it makes your code more or less readable.

[image: Output of example]

---

**Solution 1:** You can use the key `/pgf/declare function` to declare a pgfmath function, which is recognized by the pgfmath engine. This has the advantage that the scope of the function is local to the path. You can't accidentally use it somewhere else. It looks like this:

```
\path[declare function={ f(\v)=\v * (\x2-\x1); }]
    let \p1=(frame.north west), \p2=(frame.south east), \n2={.5*(\y1-\y2)} in
        node [align=center] at ({\x1+f(0.25)}, \y1-\n2) { Left }
        node [align=center] at ({\x1+f(0.75)}, \y1-\n2) { Right };
```

Note that the function definition uses the undefined symbols `\x1` and `\x2`, which are evaluated at the time when the function is *used*, not when it is *defined*. By some definitions this might be called an "impure function". If you call it somewhere else, where `\x1` or `\x2` are not defined, it will probably crash horribly.

Also, you can put it into a scope inside the let, like you requested. After the scope, the definition vanishes:

```
\path let \p1=(frame.north west), \p2=(frame.south east), \n2={.5*(\y1-\y2)} in
    {[declare function={ f(\v)=\v * (\x2-\x1); }]
        node [align=center] at ({\x1+f(0.25)}, \y1-\n2) { Left }
        node [align=center] at ({\x1+f(0.75)}, \y1-\n2) { Right }
    }
    % node at ({\x1+f(0.25)}, \y1-\n2) { Left } % Fails because f is undefined
    ;
```

---

**Solution 2:** You can use `\def` (or `\newcommand*`) to define a macro `\f`. This macro stays there until the end of the group.

Note the parentheses around the whole body of around the body of `\f`. This prevents cases like `0.5 ^ \f{0.25}` from breaking apart, because without the parentheses, this would be evaluated as `(0.5 ^ 0.25) * (\x2 - \x1)` because `^` has a higher priority than `*`.

```
\def\f#1{(#1 * (\x2 - \x1))}
\path let \p1=(frame.north west), \p2=(frame.south east), \n2={.5*(\y1-\y2)} in
    node [align=center] at ({\x1+\f{0.25}}, \y1-\n2) { Left }
    node [align=center] at ({\x1+\f{0.75}}, \y1-\n2) { Right };
```

---

Full example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{math}

\begin{document}
Using \verb|\def|:

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node (frame) [minimum width=4.5cm, minimum height=.5cm, draw=black, rounded corners=.1cm, anchor=east] at (0,0) {};
    \draw[-, dashed] let \p1=(frame.north west), \p2=(frame.south east), \n1={.5*(\x2-\x1)} in (\x1+\n1, \y1) -- (\x1+\n1, \y2);

    \def\f#1{(#1 * (\x2 - \x1))}
    \path let \p1=(frame.north west), \p2=(frame.south east), \n2={.5*(\y1-\y2)} in
    node [align=center] at ({\x1+\f{0.25}}, \y1-\n2) { Left }
    node [align=center] at ({\x1+\f{0.75}}, \y1-\n2) { Right };
\end{tikzpicture}

Using \verb|declare function|:

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node (frame) [minimum width=4.5cm, minimum height=.5cm, draw=black, rounded corners=.1cm, anchor=east] at (0,0) {};
    \draw[-, dashed] let \p1=(frame.north west), \p2=(frame.south east), \n1={.5*(\x2-\x1)} in (\x1+\n1, \y1) -- (\x1+\n1, \y2);
    \path[declare function={
        f(\v)=\v * (\x2-\x1);
    }] let \p1=(frame.north west), \p2=(frame.south east), \n2={.5*(\y1-\y2)} in
    node [align=center] at ({\x1+f(0.25)}, \y1-\n2) { Left }
    %node [align=center] at (\x1+\f{0.25}, \y1-\n2) { Left }
    node [align=center] at ({\x1+f(0.75)}, \y1-\n2) { Right };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for, thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

You can always use a `\newcommand` to avoid retyping repeated text in your document:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\newcommand{\myletcode}[2]{
    let \p1=(frame.north west), \p2=(frame.south east), \n1={#1*(\x2-\x1)}, \n2={.5*(\y1-\y2)} in node [align=center] at (\x1+\n1, \y1-\n2) { #2 }
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node (frame) [minimum width=4.5cm, minimum height=.5cm, draw=black, rounded corners=.1cm, anchor=east] at (0,0) {};
    \draw[-, dashed] let \p1=(frame.north west), \p2=(frame.south east), \n1={.5*(\x2-\x1)} in (\x1+\n1, \y1) -- (\x1+\n1, \y2);

    \path \myletcode{.25}{Left};
    \path \myletcode{.75}{Right};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Although if the problem is a node like this, you can use a `rectangle split` from `shapes.multipart`.

In this case, you should use `text width` instead of `minimum width` (see ['minimum width' no effect on node with horizontal multipart](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/311653/1952)), and the dashed separation has been drawn with a `path picture` command because I don't know how to fix an specific style for the spliting line.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.multipart}


\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    mynode/.style={
        rectangle split, 
        rectangle split parts=2, 
        rectangle split horizontal, 
        rectangle split draw splits=false, 
        path picture={%
            \draw[dashed] (path picture bounding box.north)--
            (path picture bounding box.south);},
        align=center,
    }]

    \node (frame) [mynode, text width=2.25cm, minimum height=.5cm, draw=black, rounded corners=.1cm, anchor=east] {Left\nodepart{two}Right};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

One more (simple) solution with use of the `fit` package:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{fit,
                positioning}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
node distance = 0pt,
box/.style = {text width=22.5mm, minimum height=5mm, 
              align=center, outer sep=0pt},
FIT/.style = {draw, rounded corners=1mm, inner sep=0pt, fit=#1}
                        ]
\node (n1) [box] {left};
\node (n2) [box,right=of n1] {right};
\node (n3) [FIT=(n1) (n2)] {};
\draw[dashed]   (n3.north) -- (n3.south);                  
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]